# Ant scriptmapper doesn't work as advertised?

Tags: java, ant

Based on http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html

Here's my target:

```
 <target name="ms.copy-example">
  <copy todir="${ms.custom}">
   <fileset dir="${ms.example}">
    <include name="build.xml" />
   </fileset>
   <scriptmapper language="javascript">
     self.addMappedName("dir1/"+source);
     self.addMappedName("dir2/"+source);
     self.addMappedName("dir3/"+source);
   </scriptmapper>
  </copy>
 </target>
```

I'm trying to copy one file to three places.  I don't have to use a 'scriptmapper' to do this, but I didn't see any other way to do it.  What's happening, though, is that it's only copying the file into the *first* directory in the list (dir1) and not the other two (dir2, dir3).

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scriptmapper` is working, *but* by default, the [`copy`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task only copies to one (i.e. the first mapped) target.
To get your example to work, add `enablemultiplemappings="true"` or similar to the copy:

```
<copy todir="${ms.custom}" enablemultiplemappings="true">
```

From the docs for `copy` task option `enablemultiplemappings`:

> If true the task will process to all
>   the mappings for a given source path.
>   If false the task will only process
>   the first file or directory. This
>   attribute is only relevant if there is
>   a mapper subelement. (since Ant 1.6.)